# Laravel pagination with ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination system with Laravel. On the backend side I'm returning a JSON response like this:

```
        if(isset($request->myDate)) {

            $request->validate([
                'myDate'  => 'required|date',
            ]);

            $start_date = $request->get('myDate');
            $end_date = Carbon::now();

            $my_tickets = Ticket::where('admin_id', Auth::user()->id)->whereBetween('updated_at', [$start_date, $end_date])->with(['getAdmin'])->paginate(10);

    }   

    return json_encode($my_tickets);
```

On the front-end side, I'm using an AJAX request to display the rows. My question now is how to implement the pagination system. Is there any inbuilt function from Laravel or third-party components to simplify this? Do I have to build the front end on my own? I can't access the $var->links() since it's not the same function as returning the view.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the frontend Response, you can get the page number, a total number of counts, per page, etc. if you want to use custom ajax pagination then use the following code in ajax.

```
  var page = ''
                    var count = 0;
                    if (response.total > response.perPage) {
                        if (response.page != 1) {
                            page += '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" data-page="' + (response.page - 1) + '" href="#">' + 'Previous' + '</a></li>'
                        }
                        for (i = response.page; i <= response.totalPage; i++) {
                            count++;

                            if (response.page == i) {
                                page += '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" data-page="' + i + '" href="#">' + i + '</a></li>'
                            } else {
                                page += '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" data-page="' + i + '" href="#">' + i + '</a></li>'
                            }

                            if (count == 10) break;
                        }
                        $('.number-of-show').append(' Showing ' + ((response.perPage * (response.page - 1)) + 1) + ' to ' + response.perPage * response.page + ' of ' + response.total);
                        $('.pagination').append(page);
                    }
```

**In controller**

```
   $page = '';
        if (!empty($data['page'])) {
            $page = $data['page'];
        }
        $params['perPage'] = 500;
        $params['offset'] = ($page - 1) * $params['perPage'];

        $withdrawRequestLists = $paramsData['data'];
        $total = $paramsData['total'];
        $totalPage = ceil($total / $params['perPage']);
```